# Data Conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having issue while doing these conversions:

```
string = "test \\ud83d\\ude01" #into '1f601' and vise versa.

unicode_value = 'U+1F601' #into string '\\ud83d\\ude01'
```

I have tried this method to encode

```
string.encode('utf-8') #output is "test \\ud83d\\ude01"
```

Also tried this one

```
string.force_encoding('utf-8')  #output is "test \\ud83d\\ude01"
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? What is the expected result? What is the current output? How are you doing it (your code)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Question updated please a look, thanks

Comment: Could you explain how these strings are related? I don't see a connection between them.

Comment: 'U+1F601' this a Unicode value of a emoji and '\\ud83d\\ude01' is Javascript Escape value. For this emoji . Thanks

Comment: This link clear more http://www.charbase.com/1f601-unicode-grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Hex to Unicode Char

#### "\ud83d\ude01" to smiley

According to this [table](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f601/index.htm), `"\\ud83d\\ude01"` looks like `UTF-16 (hex)`. Note that it is a standard ASCII String : `["\\", "u", "d", "8", "3", "d", "\\", "u", "d", "e", "0", "1"]`

```
str = "\\ud83d\\ude01"
hex = str.gsub("\\u",'')

smiley = [hex].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-16be').encode('utf-8')
puts smiley
#=>
```

#### 'U+1F601' to smiley

This looks like a 'UTF-8' character in hexadecimal. Note that `"U+1F601"` also is a standard ASCII string : `["U", "+", "1", "F", "6", "0", "1"]`

```
unicode_value = 'U+1F601'
hex = unicode_value.sub('U+','')
smiley = hex.to_i(16).chr('UTF-8')
puts smiley
#=>
```

## UTF-8 Hex ⟷ UTF-16 Hex

Combining both methods above :

#### "\ud83d\ude01" to 'U+1F601'

```
str = "\\ud83d\\ude01"
utf16_hex = str.gsub("\\u",'')
smiley = [utf16_hex].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-16be').encode('utf-8')
utf8_hex = smiley.ord.to_s(16).upcase
new_str = "U+#{utf8_hex}"
puts new_str
#=> "U+1F601"
```

#### 'U+1F601' to "\ud83d\ude01"

```
unicode_value = 'U+1F601'
hex = unicode_value.sub('U+','')
smiley = hex.to_i(16).chr('UTF-8')
puts smiley.force_encoding('utf-8').encode('utf-16be').unpack('H*').first.gsub(/(....)/,'\u\1')
#=> "\ud83d\ude01"
```

There might be an easier way to do this, but I couldn't find it.

## Using this code

```
def utf16_hex_to_unicode_char(utf16_hex)
  hex = utf16_hex.gsub("\\u",'')
  [hex].pack('H*').force_encoding('utf-16be').encode('utf-8')
end

def replace_all_utf16_hex(string)
  string.gsub(/(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){2}/){|hex| utf16_hex_to_unicode_char(hex)}
end

puts replace_all_utf16_hex("Hello \\ud83d\\ude01, I just bought a \\uD83D\\uDC39")
#=> "Hello , I just bought a "
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply what I should do if the string contains text plus emoji(s) e.g. "Hello \\ud83d\\ude01".

Comment: Code has been Updated

Comment: No problem. I like getting my hands dirty with pack/unpack/gsub/force_encoding! I'd be interested to know if there's an easier way.

Comment: How can we do the reverse of this e.g. string containing smileys to utf-8
string  = "ok test body \r\n-- \r\n test"
string.force_encoding('utf-8').encode('utf-16be')
#"ok test body \u{1F601} \u{1F601}\u{1F601}\r\n-- \r\n test"
I want this output "ok test body \\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\r\n-- \r\n test"

Comment: Hi Eric Duminil, I have come across this emoji ‍❤️‍‍ http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html#1f469_200d_2764_fe0f_200d_1f48b_200d_1f469
Now the string = "test \\ud83d\\udc69\\u200d\\u2764\\ufe0f\\u200d\\ud83d\\udc8b\\u200d\\ud83d\\udc69 test" and the above code fail.

Comment: There should be a Ruby gem for this.