# Ruby: Smiley to utf-8 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I convert this

```
string = "ok test body \r\n-- \r\n test"
```

Into this

```
"ok test body \\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\r\n-- \r\n test"
```

I have tried this

```
string.encode('utf-16be','utf-8')
```

which convert it into this form

```
#"ok test body \u{1F601} \u{1F601}\u{1F601}\r\n-- \r\n test"
```

I think i need regular expression to solve this. Can anyone tell me how to do that. Thanks

Comment: this is utf-8 string i believe.  https://repl.it/FLVi

Comment: When I do `puts "ok test body \u{1F601} \u{1F601}\u{1F601}\r\n-- \r\n test"` it prints the smily faces. What is it exactly that you think is not working?

Comment: But I want this output "ok test body \\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\r\n-- \r\n test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41549452/6419007), this code just applies the `'U+1F601' to "\ud83d\ude01"` conversion to non-ascii characters  :

```
encoded_string = string.gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]/) do |non_ascii|
  non_ascii.force_encoding('utf-8')
           .encode('utf-16be')
           .unpack('H*').first
           .gsub(/(....)/,'\u\1')
end
```

For :

```
string = "ok test body \r\n-- \r\n test"
```

it outputs:

```
"ok test body \\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\r\n-- \r\n test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to [Eric Duminil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41698288/477037):

```
string.gsub(/[\u{10000}-\u{10FFFF}]/) { |m|
  '\u%s\u%s' % m.encode('UTF-16BE').unpack('H4H4')
}
#=> "ok test body \\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\\ud83d\\ude01\r\n-- \r\n test"
```

The regular expression matches code points U+10000 to U+10FFFF, i.e. characters from the [Supplementary Planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane). In UTF-16, these are represented as so-called *surrogate pairs*.

Each matched character is split via [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-unpack) into its high and low surrogate: (the pattern `H4` extracts 4 hexadecimal characters, i.e. 2 bytes or 16 bits)

```
''.encode('UTF-16BE').unpack('H4H4')
#=> ["d83d", "de01"]
```

The result is formatted via [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-25):

```
'\u%s\u%s' % ["d83d", "de01"]
#=> "\\ud83d\\ude01"
```